# How to fix 'Magento_Store' data-version not available and duplicated entry?

Tags: magento2, database, magerun

I'm receiving some error messages related to the `Magento_Store` module when I try to run the downgrade version via Magerun and when I try to change it too, as you can see in these images below.

[image: 'Magento_Store' duplicated key]
[image: 'Magento_Store' data-version not available]

I tried to remove it via SQL but after a **setup:upgrade** this issue returns.

How could I fix it?

Comment: Here may be something wrong in your `setup_module` table in your database. There may be entry available with **Magento_Store** that is creating that issue.

Comment: I removed then I ran setup:upgrade to populate the DB again but the issue persists.